# Is open set in Banach space countable?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is open set in Banach space countable? If there exists those kind of open set, could you give me an example? If it is not, how to prove that all open sets in Banach space are uncountable? Thank you.

Comment: Try the smallest possible Banach space.

Comment: Hint 2: Every Banach spaces contain a smallest Banach space.

Comment: To closevoter(s): Consider: 1. Trivial case. 2. Finite field. 3. Typical Banach space. Is the question still too simple  to ask?

Comment: Thank you very much. Is the smallest Banach space countable?

Comment: Excuse me, could you please recommend me some reference books about: smallest Banach space, trivial case and typical Banach space. I tried many ways but still could not search those.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke : I am the one to vote to close. Why do you think that I think the question is simple?

Comment: @JohnMa Sorry, but I didn't imagine other reason of closing this question. I understand, that it looks as a typical question of a new user, but it has an unexpected depth.

Comment: It is the reason of "missing content", @PrzemysławScherwentke . If it is about real, complex Banach spaces, it seems that the OP don't even know one example of Banach space. Thus it seems hard to write an answer that the OP would understand. (For example, do you think the OP will understand the answer given by Robert below?)

Comment: @John Ma:  you raise an interesting point.  In response, all I can say is that I have occasionally mulled over similar questions (perhaps even this very question), just to see how the answer worked out in detail, though well I knew all the definitions etc. invoked.  So that legitimizes it in my mind at least.  I guess I feel difficulty is not an absolute thing, but somewhat of a subjective quality.

Comment: @JohnMa I must completely agree with you, that OP was unprepared for this question. Without potential depth of nonstandard cases it would be a natural candidate for closing. But now we have a trivial, one point, case; an obvious non-zero-dimensional case over reals, where an open set must contain an ordinary interval; and the rest which have a chance to appear here, if we leave enough time for it.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke:  somehow I see non-standard Banach spaces entering my consciousness in the very near future . . .

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comment stream:  it appears to me this question is neither too simple nor too difficult.

***Caveat:***  Based on the comments of Eric Wofsey (see below), I believe I need to qualify my remarks here by saying that I am assuming the Banach spaces under consideration are non-trivial, by which I mean they contain more vectors than the single element $0$.  I make the following

***Observation:***  Let $B \ne \{0\}$ be a Banach space.  Then for every $r \in \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, $\exists v \in B, \Vert v \Vert = r$; for if $r = 0$, we may take $v = 0$; if $r > 0$, choose any $0 \ne v \in B$; then $\Vert v \Vert \ne 0$ and we may set $w = (r/\Vert v \Vert)v$; then $\Vert w \Vert = \Vert (r/\Vert v \Vert)v \Vert = r/\Vert v \Vert \Vert v \Vert = r$.  Furthermore, if $B \ne \{0\}$ the set $S(v, \epsilon) = \{w \in B \mid \Vert w - v \Vert = \epsilon$ is non-empty, since there is a $y \in B$ with $\Vert y \Vert = \epsilon$; then $\Vert (y + x) - x \Vert = \Vert y \Vert = \epsilon$.

Hopefully this ***Observation*** clarifies the discussion somewhat.

So I read this question as, "Is there a countable open set in any non-trvial Banach space?"
And with this reading, I answer it it the negative, based on the following:

Let $U$ be open in the Banach space $B$, and let $x_0 \in U$.  Since $U$ is open, there is a non-empty open ball (i.e., one with $\epsilon \ne 0$)

$B(x_0, \epsilon) \subset \bar B(x_0, \epsilon) \subset U, \tag 1$

i.e., the closure $\bar B(x_0, \epsilon)$ of $B(x_0, \epsilon)$ is contained in $U$.  For $t \in (0, 1)$, the sphere

$S(x_0, t\epsilon) = \{x \in B \mid \Vert x - x_0 \Vert = t\epsilon \} \subsetneq \bar B(x_0, \epsilon). \tag 2$

For any fixed element $y \in S(x_0, \epsilon) = \partial{\bar B(x_0, \epsilon)}$,

$x_0 + t(y - x_0) \in S(x_0, t\epsilon). \tag 3$

Now it is easy to see that if $t_1 \ne t_2$, we have

$x_0 + t_1(y - x_0) \ne x_0 + t_2(y - x_0); \tag 4$

otherwise,

$x_0 + t_1(y - x_0) = x_0 + t_2(y - x_0) \Longrightarrow t_1(y - x_0) = t_2(y - x_0)$
$\Longrightarrow (t_1 - t_2)(y - x_0) = 0 \Longrightarrow y - x_0 = 0 \Longrightarrow y = x_0, \tag 5$

a contradiction.  Thus(4) binds, and this implies the map sending $t \in (0, 1) \mapsto x_0 + t(y - x_0)$ is injective.  Since $(0, 1)$ is uncountable, the set of vectors

$\{ x_0 + t(y - x_0) \mid t \in (0, 1) \} \subset U \tag 6$

is uncountable; thus $U$ contains an uncountable subset, and hence cannot itself be countable.

Comment: You assume $S(x_0,\epsilon)$ is nonempty, which is not always true.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  OK, I'll bite:  for what Banach space is it false?

Comment: @EricWofsey:  Maybe I should look into the Banach space $\{ 0 \}$?  I guess in this case, the open $\{0\}$ is countable . . . maybe I should edit my answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a non-empty open subset of the Banach space $B,$ where $B\ne \{0\}.$

If $0\not \in S$ we may take some $v\in S$ with $v\ne 0 .$

If $0\in S$ we can still take some $v\in S$ with $v\ne 0,$ because for some $r>0$ we have $\{y\in B: \|y-0\|<r\}\subset S,$ and there exists $u\in B$ with $u\ne 0,$ so we may take  $v=ru/(2\|u\|).$

So with $0\ne v\in S,$ take $r>0$ such that $\{u\in B:\|u-v\|<r\}\subset S.$ For $t\in [0,r/\|v\|)$ let $f(t)=v(1+t).$ Then $f(t)\in S.$

Now $f$ is $1$-to-$1$ because $f(t_1)=f(t_2)\implies (t_1-t_2)v=0\implies t_1=t_2$ (because $v\ne 0$).

So $f$ is an injection from the uncountable set $[0, r/\|v\|)$ into S, so $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: We cannot prove that $all$ open subsets of B are uncountable because the empty set is always an open subset.

Comment: If we do not consider empty set, this answer is right? I think it is right but I am not sure. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeh, I got it. Thank you